# Can not use a lib function when concat several libs into one

Tags: javascript, html, gulp

I try to learn gulp. I have a task which concat all js lib into one lib.min.js

```
gulp.task("lib-js:build", function () {
    return gulp.src(templates[template].src.libsJs)
        .pipe(concat("libs.min.js"))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(templates[template].dist.js));
});
```

variable `templates[template].src.libsJs` is a array with following values:

```
var templates = {
    balmy: {
        dist: {
            default: "templates/balmy/dist",
            html: "templates/balmy/dist/",
            js: "templates/balmy/dist/resources/js/",
            css: "templates/balmy/dist/resources/css/",
            fonts: "templates/balmy/dist/resources/fonts/",
            img: "templates/balmy/dist/resources/img/"
        },
        src: {
            html: "templates/balmy/*.html",
            js: "templates/balmy/resources/js/*.js",
            css: "templates/balmy/resources/css/balmy.css",
            fonts: "templates/balmy/resources/fonts/**/*.*",
            fontsCss: "templates/balmy/resources/css/fonts.css",
            img: "templates/balmy/resources/img/**/*.*",
            libsJs: [
                "lib/jquery/v3.1.1/jquery-3.1.1.min.js",
                "lib/jquery-easing/v1.3/jquery.easing.min.js",
                "lib/bootstrap/v4.0.0-alpha.6/bootstrap.min.js",
                "lib/magnific-popup/v1.1.0/magnific-popup.js",
                "lib/owl-carousel/v2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js",
                "lib/bootstrap-multiselect/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js",
                "lib/bootstrap-multiselect/bootstrap-multiselect-collapsible-groups.min.js",
                "lib/viewportchecker/v1.8.7/viewportchecker.min.js"
            ],
            libsCss: [
                "lib/owl-carousel/v2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.css",
                "lib/owl-carousel/v2.2.1/owl.theme.default.min.css",
                "lib/animation/v3.5.1/animate.min.css",
                "lib/magnific-popup/v1.1.0/magnific-popup.css",
                "lib/bootstrap-multiselect/bootstrap-multiselect.min.css"
            ]
        },
        needBootstrap: true
    }
}
```

Where `templates` is variable which describe all possible site template. When I excecute:

```
gulp build --template balmy
```

I also set parametr with name of template which I would like build.

After that I include this js file into my html and try to use a owl carousel function:

```
<script src="resources/js/libs.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".all-events-carousel").owlCarousel({
            loop: true,
            margin: 10,
            items: 1,
            animateOut: 'slideOutDown',
            animateIn: 'flipInX',
            autoplay: true
        })
    });
</script>
```

This code close to bottom of body. In browser console I see next exception:

[image: stacke trace]

But if delete from html a concat js and add all concated js files it will work fine.

This is the result [libs.min.js](https://yadi.sk/d/ZWh6pAun3MJvWx) which only concatenated and didn't minified (without call uglify)

Maybe anybody know why does it happen?

Comment: What is `template` in `templates[template]`?

Comment: Also, if all those "lib" files are already minified, you're just wasting CPU cycles running them through `uglify`

Comment: @Phil, I changed my question and added information about templates variable.

Comment: Is that a typo `/magnific-pupup.js` ?

Comment: @Deliaz, yes, you are right

Comment: Can you upload the minified result file into somewhere to let us examine it?

Comment: @ZoltánTamási, I added the result minified file several days ago and wrote about this upder your answer. Can you download it [here](https://yadi.sk/d/ZWh6pAun3MJvWx)?

Comment: Sorry I missed that completely. I was having a look at it but couldn't see any issue at first glance unfortunately. I would place some debug logs in the minified file where owlCarousel adds itself to $.fn for example, also I would log $.fn at several places to see if any plugin reinitializes it in some way, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your attached `libs.min.js` file and you are missing [Tether](http://tether.io/) for bootstrap 4. See this question to resolve it: [How to fix the error; 'Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34567939/how-to-fix-the-error-error-bootstrap-tooltips-require-tether-http-github-h) .
I quickly tried to put together your `libs.min.js` together with Tether from CDN and the owlCarousel CSS in an `index.html` file and it works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
        <script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
        <script src="libs.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
            <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
            <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
            <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
            <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
            <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
            <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
            <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
            <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
            <div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
            <div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
            <div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
            <div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
                loop:true,
                margin:10,
                nav:true,
                responsive:{
                    0:{
                        items:1
                    },
                    600:{
                        items:3
                    },
                    1000:{
                        items:5
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hm.. thank you.. I will check this. But it is not clear to me. When I included all libs without concatenation them into one file I also didn't add the thecher lib. Yes I saw the exception in the browser about this but all worked fine. Are you realy think that missing the thecher lib it is the main problem?

Comment: Yes, since all libraries are included in one file the execution of the javascript ends when the error occurs and the OwlCarousel is placed afterwards so it never gets a chance to execute. When you included them separately the browser tried to execute bootstrap script and failed. Then it went on to execute the other scripts included. That is why it worked.

Comment: I didn't read links that you attached yet. But I tried to add `techer.js` to libs (before the `bootstrap.min.js`) which I concatenate into one file. And all worked. Thank you very much for your time. I suppose this is stupid mistake but it cool to resolved it!

Comment: Can you give one more advise? Is it possible that after concatenation several libs into one file they will be conflict and I get incorrect work of their functions? How can I be sure that all fine and I can work with this file and will not afraid bugs? Is it enought to validate files by the `gulp js-validation` plugin (look to the answer from @lofihelsinki)? Can you give more detail answer for this theme and I will mark the answer like correct and give to you the bounty.

Comment: When concatenating multiple libraries there is definitely a possibility for conflicts, especially when libraries pollute the global scope. Usually all libraries expose a single global namespace by default. (like jQuery exposes `$` and/or `jQuery`) and you only have to worry that there are no conflicts between them. They provide some mechanism for controlling this with `noConflict` methods which remove the global namespaces but then you must take care of correctly passing around the reference to the libraries in your code,see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression

Comment: Also have a look at [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) for advanced topics on bundling resources in order not to worry when creating a single file that contains all libraries and resources.

Comment: Thank you one more time, I will learn these resources tomorrow

Answer (score 4):

It's not a good practice usually to run the `uglify` plugin on already minified files. I can see that most of your referred JavaScript files are already minified.

Minification in general *can* potentially remove exposed functionality.

Please try to remove the `uglify` call from the chain and see if that works.

Comment: I already tried this several days ago and it didn't resolve the problem

Comment: I attached the result `libs.min.js` to the question

Comment: Can you provide an example of when this would happen?

Comment: @Our_Benefactors I saw this scenario only when one tries to rely on variable, function or class names at runtime and those get renamed at minification. For example see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264109/microsoft-ajax-minifier-renames-my-function-names I could tell a more natural real-life example as well, for example when using TypeScript you're almost always stuck whenever you'd want to rely on `myclass.constructor.name` as it will likely be something like `"a"` because TS first introduces the class and then exposes it in an explicit export or namespace property assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I would add [JS syntax checking](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jsvalidate) before and after `concat()` and leave out `uglify()` for the time being. That might help to narrow down the problem.

```
const jsValidate = require('gulp-jsvalidate');

gulp.task("lib-js:build", function () {
    return gulp.src(templates[template].src.libsJs)
       .pipe(jsValidate())
       .pipe(concat("libs.min.js"))
       .pipe(jsValidate())
       .pipe(gulp.dest(templates[template].dist.js));
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried now but the js validate plugin didn't find any errors. Task worked clearly and outputted to the log only information abount starting and finishing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a naming conflict in those js files, there are two file both has a variable named $ and the latter is not a jQuery obj, and when you add files separately the jQuery load latter exactly. You can do a search in those files.